# resConfigs attribute does not work as I expected, Reads from a different language, Not the device language

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

My app support two languages (English and Arabic languages)

```
values -> strings.xml (Contains English texts)
values-ar -> strings.xml (Contains Arabic texts)
```

I added the FirebaseUI library inside my app and I need to use English and Arabic languages only from that library and exclude other languages. Here is what I did

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "ar"
    }
}
```

**Here is the result after a few tests**

1. If the device language was the Arabic language, The whole app will read the texts from `values-ar -> strings.xml` `(That is okay)`
2. If the device language was the English language, The whole app will read the texts from `values -> strings.xml` `(That is okay)`
3. If the device language was the Spanish or French language, The whole app will read the texts from `values -> strings.xml` and sometimes will read from `values-ar -> strings.xml` `(That is not okay), The problem happens when changing the language from the settings`

This is so confusing, How can I solve the problem?